# Junk in directory name created with "mkdir" via CreateProcessW?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

After running the following code everything does as I would like except the folder shows this: test2﷽﷽ꮫꮫꮫꮫﻮﻮﻮ

What is going on here?

```
            std::string arrString[3] = {" /C mkdir C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test1"," /C mkdir C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test2"," /C mkdir C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test3"};
            LPWSTR cmd =L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
            int i;


            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
                PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
                vector<wchar_t> cmdline(arrString[i].begin(), arrString[i].end());
                CreateProcessW(cmd, &cmdline[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
                OutputDebugStringW(L"My output\nstring.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Out of all the results possible, that is sort of pretty. Well, except for the 4 boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmdline` is not properly ASCIIZ terminated. You can check if this is the cause just adding an ending 0 (note: not tested and a quick hack):

```
cmdline.push_back(0);
```

Comment: In the `CreateProcess` line correct? `CreateProcessW(cmd, &cmdline.push_back(0)[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);`

Comment: No, just put the code I show you just before the line calling `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you. Care to point me in the direction that might show me exactly is going on? Documentation or a keyword I can lookup. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is just easier than it seems. The actual bytes that go into `cmdline` are the correct name of the file, but for the call to `CreateProcessW`, it is a prerequisite that the characters end with a 0 (character `'\0'`), so this is what that line adds to the end. Note however that this is inefficient. If you just used `std::wstring` for `arrString` you could have used just `arrString[i]` in the call to `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: @Diego : Assuming you meant `&arrString[i][0]` (as `arrString[i]` would not compile, since `std::wstring` has no implicit conversion to `wchar_t*`), that would only strictly be legal under C++11; in C++03, `std::string` is not required to store its contents contiguously.

Comment: @idljam: you're right. Then the most easy first. Just define `arrString` as `const wchar_t* arrString[]`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thank you for the pointer. Although I am not entirely clear what this does.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are not passing a null-terminated string to `CreateProcessW()`, that is why you end up with extra characters in the folder name.  On a separate note, rather than use `CreateProcessW()` to invoke `mkdir`, you should use `CreateDirectoryW()` instead.  Then you can change `arrString` from `std::string` to `std::wstring` and get rid of the `std::vector` completely.